# Woocommerce product images in lightbox ix not showing on product detail page

Tags: wordpress

I have a website where product gallery is not working on product detail page, I have tried to add third party plugin but nothing seems to working.

Here when you click on product image, it should open in lightbox as product gallery.

https://bosheimsmarken.no/produkt/reinrot-te-med-tea-shotnon-binding-subscriptions/

Comment: can you provide more info about your problem

Comment: Seems that working at here. Is it solved already?

Comment: I have fixed it now with below solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to install this plugin and check if there is option to disable this gallery in theme options or woocommerce options.

> Product Gallery Slider for Woocommerce by codeixer

Also add this code in your functions.php in active theme

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'bbloomer_remove_zoom_lightbox_theme_support', 99 );

function bbloomer_remove_zoom_lightbox_theme_support() { 
remove_theme_support( 'wc-product-gallery-zoom' );
remove_theme_support( 'wc-product-gallery-lightbox' );
remove_theme_support( 'wc-product-gallery-slider' );
}
```